# How to set locale for numbers in angular 2.0

Tags: angular, numbers, locale, angular2-pipe

The number format in Swiss German is like "100'000.00" (not "100,000.00"). How can I change that? I tried to change the settings in number_pipe.js from en-US to de-CH without success.

```
var defaultLocale: string = 'de-CH';
```

Is there a workaround or do I have to implement my own pipe?

Comment: You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50886941/7120290)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [**locale-number**.pipe.ts](https://github.com/robisim74/angular2localization/blob/83e413f812cbe3e5e9982a1d9b069750faf62887/src/pipes/locale-number.pipe.ts) or

you could create a simple pipe based on NumeralJs to format numbers

https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js

Answer (score 16):

If you only need one locale for your app, you can as of now (@angular ~2.4.0) register the locale provider in @NgModule.

```js
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "de-CH"}
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: You have to add: import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

Comment: And you might have to use the built in `DecimalPipe` in Angular, eg. `{{myNumberVar|number:'1.0-2'}}` See docs (https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

Answer (score 3):

Following is the my solution and it will help to someone.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'amountConverter'
})
export class AmountConverterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number | string, locale?: string): string {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2
    }).format(Number(value));
  }

}
```

In the html you can use as follows

```
 <span class="strong">{{Price  | amountConverter:locale}}</span>
```

Number format will change according to value of locale.

Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for me was the famous https://www.npmjs.com/package/numeral package. (he works with same logical of the `moment.js`)

To install it: `npm i numeral@2.0.6` and with types `npm i --save-dev @types/numeral@0.0.22`

At your `ts` file you can use as follow:

```
`R$ ${numeral(<your-model-value>).value().toLocaleString()}`
```

For HTML template you can create a `Pipe` like this:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import * as numeral from 'numeral';

@Pipe({
  name: 'numberLocale'
})
export class NumberLocalePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    const numeralNumber = numeral(value);

    return numeralNumber.value().toLocaleString();
  }
}
```

Additionally, for **currency** (and locales) a good strategy is use the package `ng2-currency-mask` for currency **masks in HTML** (but on `ts` files you may should "translate" the binded value in the model with `numeral` before *save* your model object.

Using `ng2-currency-mask` on HTML Template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model.value"
   [options]="{ prefix: 'R$ ', thousands: '.', decimal: ',' }"
   allowNegative="false" currencyMask>
```

And on `ts` before *save* the model:

```
if(this.model.value)
   this.model.value = numeral(this.model.value).value();
```

https://github.com/cesarrew/ng2-currency-mask