# separators of thousands in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

i have tried this one in my proyect:

```
<div padding *ngIf="TotalAPagar">
    $ {{TotalAPagar | number }}  
</div>
```

my variable is called `TotalAPagar`, and I'm using number pipe, but it shows the value like this **1,000,500**.

I need that to change the numbering convention to `dots`. Eg. **1.000.000**

I have been reading about in the docs in angular but doesn't have any example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set locale for numbers in angular 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684360/how-to-set-locale-for-numbers-in-angular-2-0)

Comment: You shouldn't do that as decimal numbers use dot to mark fractions.

Comment: Have you looked at the `currency` pipe? The locale-specific aspects can be handled via the LOCALE_ID provider. If you want dynamic locales, you could consider customiizing/subclassing the currency pipe.

Comment: @coderek there is a country called "germany", where 1.234.567,12€ would be one million twohundredthirtyfourthousand fivehundredsixtyseven euros and 12 cents, so.... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

​After reading in forums and docs about angular js y javascript i found a method that puts the numbers in format and currency, that method is toLocaleString(), is a method from javascript that helps to put it in the currency or languaje that you need.

i search the name of the country that i need with the method and show me the info that need about. (http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/es-CO/), In my case was colombia.

in my functions i just have to add the .toLocaleString('es-CO') to the result and put the value with the specified currency.

for example:

> this.TotalAPagar =
>   (this.calcularDescuentosLiquidacion(this.TotalDevengadoValor,
>   this.sueldoPendientePorCancelarValor, this.item.libranza,
>   this.item.prestamo_empleado)+
>   this.calcularIndemnizacion(this.item.promedio_salario,
>   this.item.fecha_fin_contrato,
>   this.item.fecha_inicio_contrato)).toLocaleString('es-CO');

Answer (score 6):

I think that there are two ways to resolve this problem:

---

**1. You can trying overwrite DecimalPipe from *@angular/common* library:**

In this way:

**point-replacer.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import {DecimalPipe} from "@angular/common";

@Pipe({
    name: 'pointReplacer'
})
export class PointReplacerPipe extends DecimalPipe {

  transform(value: any, digits?: string): string {
        return super.transform(value, digits).replace(',', '.');


    }
}
```

and in your **html code**:

```
<div padding *ngIf="TotalAPagar">
    $ {{TotalAPagar | pointReplacer }}  
</div>
```

---

**2. You can write your own pipe, which replaces characters and use **double pipe** in your html code**

Try in this way:

**point-replacer.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'pointReplacer'
})

export class PointReplacerPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, args: any[]): string {
        if(value) {
          return value.replace(',', '.');
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

and in your **html code**:

```
<div padding *ngIf="TotalAPagar">
    $ {{TotalAPagar | number | pointReplacer }}  
</div>
```

---

No matter which method you choose, don't forget to declare your own pipe in module, where you use it:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PointReplacerPipe],
  providers: [PointReplacerPipe]
})
```

Comment: This is not a robust solution. How would you adapt it to Indian number grouping, as in `1,00,000`? Numbers and currencies should be formatted using number and currency formatting libraries, not by ad hoc string manipulations.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is a cleaner solution:

Import LOCALE_ID in app.modules.ts

```
import {ErrorHandler, NgModule, LOCALE_ID} from '@angular/core';
```

and define in providers like this:

```
  providers: [
    PouchServiceProvider,
    DbProvider, {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useValue: "nl-NL"
    }
  ]
```

this will auto choose the seperator id, based on local_id