# Does Angular i18n support Devanagari digits?

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I'm working on i18n in Angular 8 app. I have registered locale Hindi ('hi') using following code inside `app.module.ts`.

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeHi from '@angular/common/locales/hi';
import localeHiExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/hi';

registerLocaleData(localeHi, 'hi', localeHiExtra);
```

It changed the digits and month text inside  which is as expected. But, when I use `DatePipe` on date inside a template, it just converted month name to Devanagari and didn't converted digits of date. Same is happening with `DecimalPipe`.

I even tried to specify locale manually to these pipes, but it didn't work. Why is it behaving differently with `<mat-datepicker>` and `DatePipe`? I'm doing something wrong or is it intended behaviour? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323210/how-to-format-number-based-on-user-locale-in-angular-2

Comment: Thanks! But actually my issue is inconsistency in the behavior and not the workaround. I want it to be handled by Angular in consistent way but surprisingly it's not doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While finding solution, I found that in Angular Material Datepicker, I'm using `MomentDateAdapter`. It's `moment.js` which has Devanagari digits included in its Hindi locale, but Angular doesn't have these digits.

That's why I'm not able to get Devanagari digits in other places. Though, I wish it could be consistent in all places.