# Use 2 pipes in Angular- HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pipe

I use curreny pipe, but it add digits after dot.
How to remove them?
The result of  `{{ 1111111 | | currency:'ILS' }}` is *1,111,111.00*.
I want to remove the "*.00*"

I tried to use both pipes, curreny and number:
`{{ 1111111 | number: '2.0' | currency:'ILS' }}`
but it don't give any result.

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Comment: 1,111,111.
{{ 1111111  | currency:'ILS' }} result is  1,111,111.00

Comment: You are getting this error: InvalidPipeArgument: '1,111,111 is not a number' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe'.

Maybe use only the currency pipe and have a look at setting locale for numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684360/how-to-set-locale-for-numbers-in-angular-2-0/43099150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
{{ 1111111 | currency:'ILS': 'symbol':'1.0-0' }}
```

symbol will remove zero's.

Please read the documentation is really explained in details. https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

Happy coding

Comment: if the number can has decimals, use '1.0-0' to get rounded number

Comment: Yes I missed 0-0, but that should resolve his issue. Thanks for explanation